# How to convert from UITextField to Decimal

Tags: swift, uitextfield, decimal

I have a UITextField with a decimal pad. I try to do some math with the value in it but I can't figure it out.

To get a string as an int, I do this:

```
let number:Int? = Int(self.number.text!)
```

...which works.

But I don't understand why I can't do the following for decimal:

```
let decimalNumber:Decimal? = Int(self.decimalNumber.text!)
```

I get an error message:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Decimal' with an argument of list of type '(String)'

With my javascript knowledge, I find it hard to deal with values coming from a field on iOS :)

Comment: Decimal has a String initializer  `Decimal(string: number.text ?? "")`  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/1780123-init

Comment: why go with decimal when you have already options for Double and Float?

Comment: Please post real code and errors. It is not possible that the line `let decimalNumber:Decimal? = Int(self.decimalNumber.text!)` resulted in the error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Decimal' with an argument of list of type '(String)'"

Comment: thanks @LeoDabus I see, it works like this.